# sudo does nothing and su doesn't accept my password

Tags: command-line, sudo, su

When I type `sudo`, the command doesn't seem to do anything useful. I expected to be asked for my password or to get a root shell, but instead I only get this:

```
$ sudo
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]
            [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] file ...
```

`su` seems to start normally, but does not accept my password. I cannot log in as a super user.

Is there a problem with my installation, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please provide the error message from sudo.

Comment: Please explain how it "no longer accepts sudo", what error message or what else? Include it in question(click edit below Q), also check `visudo` as @guiverc explained. Also, you should be in `sudo` group, check it with `groups` command

Comment: `sudo` looks fine from the output. What do you get after `sudo -i` or `sudo su`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the information provided, your system is working as expected.

You need to provide sudo with either a command, or an option or both (depending which option you choose).

An easy method to test:

```
sudo -s
```

This should prompt you for your password, after which it should give you a root shell.

The `su` (*switch user*) command by default with no arguments logs the user in as root, but you need to give root's password and not your own for it to succeed. By default on Ubuntu, root has no password so `su` returns `authentication failure`. Perhaps that was the message you saw? If you want to, you can use `sudo` to run `su` meaning you only need enter your own password, but it is simpler to start a root shell with `sudo -i` or `sudo -s` (i.e. without calling an additional program).

Comment: Sorry, I feel like an Idiot now :D
I always used Sudo with a command like sudo apt-get install ****
This time I was just trying to go in and do some work  with just sudo....

I see the error of my ways :( "humbled"